# Common lisp — why isn't this symbol external?

Tags: package, common-lisp, asdf

I'm trying to run tests in ASDF, which looks like this:

```
;;;; foo.asd

(defsystem "foo/tests"
  :depends-on ("foo"
               "fiveam")
  :components ((:module "tests"
                :components
                ((:file "main"))))
  :perform (test-op (op c) (symbol-call :fiveam '#:run! 'foo/tests:all-tests))
```

And my `tests/main.lisp` file starts off like this:

```
;;;; tests/main.lisp

(defpackage foo/tests
  (:use :cl
        :foo
        :fiveam)
  (:export :#run! :#all-tests))
(in-package :foo/tests)
```

When I run `(asdf:test-system 'foo)` in my REPL, I get dropped into the debugger with a `LOAD-SYSTEM-DEFINITION-ERROR`. The debugger is complaining that `The symbol "ALL-TESTS" is not external in the FOO/TESTS package.`

However, I am clearly exporting the symbol in the `foo/tests` package. Can somebody please tell me what I'm missing here and why the Lisp compiler isn't seeing the external symbol? Thank you very much.

Comment: `foo.asd` is being read before `main.lisp` is loaded, so the `defpackage` hasn't been executed yet.

Comment: @Barmar: that's what the `symbol-call` form solves.

Comment: @svante: `foo/tests:all-tests` is an external symbol in a not yet defined (?) package. How can that be solved by `symbol-call`, which is not executed at read-time? Somehow he needs to have that package already available, before the DEFSYSTEM form can be read?

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Sorry, you're both right, I had only glanced over the form.  As written, it only solves the problem for `fiveam:run!`, not for the argument.

Comment: It's long been said that the choice to describe packages in Chapter 11 of CLTL was deliberate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for an uninterned symbol is `#:foo`, not `:#foo`.

You also need to resolve the symbols in the `:perform` form at run-time, e. g. through `uiop:find-symbol*`, just like you use `uiop:symbol-call` there.

```
:perform (test-op (op c)
           (symbol-call :fiveam '#:run!
                        (find-symbol* '#:all-tests '#:foo/tests)))
```

Or, since you seem to export a `run!` function from your test package, you might want to call that instead of `fiveam:run!`:

```
:perform (test-op (op c)
           (symbol-call '#:foo/tests '#:run!))
```